# Programmatically fetching AppDynamics Transaction Scorecard information using REST

Tags: appdynamics

I need to fetch the transaction scorecard data of a business application using the REST API of AppDynamics .

Following is the a sample view of AppDynamics Transaction Scorecard

[image]

I have done through the AppDynamics REST API documentation to some extent,but not found anything so far .
Can anybody have any idea on this ?

Comment: Do you want the aggregated numbers of transactions per bucket (as in your screenshots) or something else? What is the timeframe you are looking for?

Comment: I want to display the data similar to the captured in the image i.e. the percentage and the count .

Answer (score 1):

In order to capture this data follow these steps:

- Login to AppDynamics=
- Select the application you wish to get these metrics from
- Go into Metric Browser (left nav)
- Go into overall application performance, in this case number of slow, very slow, stall, errors
- For each of these right click on the metric and "copy rest url"
- Use those in your code to pull the data

Pointer, you can also adjust the time periods in the metric browser to adjust the time.

Hope this is helpful.

Comment: Hi thanks for your helpful input ,I would try them and share my updates